# check/determine if QString contains html

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

Since I wasn't able to find a suitable solution here, I wanted to Q&A this question:

Is there a way to determine if a `QString` is made of html, i.e. is rich-text, (or at least, contains html)?

This may be the case for unknown/`QVariant` calls to `setData` of data editors in the [table/view model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be to use [Qt::mightBeRichText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#mightBeRichText) for `QString`:

```
#include <QTextDocument>

QString ensurePlainText(const QString& text)
{
    QString out;
    if (Qt::mightBeRichText(text))
    {
        // is html -> convert to plain text
        QTextDocument text;
        text.setHtml(value.toString());
        out = text.toPlainText();
    }
    else
    {
        out = text;
    }
    return out;
}
```

It is important to note that the presented method [uses a heuristic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#mightBeRichText). It may fail to detect html or falsely detect html in a non-html text. The former may return html tags in the string. The latter would, for instance, strip newline characters from the text.